# How to compare reversed input to original input?

Tags: java

I'm trying to debug my program so that it includes sentences as potential palindromes. Right now it only tells me that an individual word in reverse is a palindrome but it always tells me that a sentence is not a palindrome even though it is.

I have tried changing original.equals(reverse) to reverse.equals(original) but I continued to get the same output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordPlay {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    // Variable declarations
    String original, reverse = "";
    boolean lipE = true;
    boolean lipS = true;
    boolean palindrome = true;
    boolean alliteration = true;

    // Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
    original = input.nextLine();
    original = original.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("The input that you entered was: " + original);


    // Determine whether a input is a lipogram
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
       if(original.charAt(i) == 'e' || original.charAt(i) == 'E' )
          lipE = false;
    if(lipE) {
      System.out.println("The input is a lipogram. ");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("The input is not a lipogram avoiding the 
letter E.");
    }


    // Determine whether a input is a lipogram
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
       if(original.charAt(i) == 's' || original.charAt(i) == 'S' )
          lipS = false;
    if(lipS) {
      System.out.println("The input is a lipogram. ");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("The input is not a lipogram avoiding the letter S.");
    }
    // Determine whether or not an input is a palindrome.
    // Compare the original input to the reversed input.
    double length = original.length();
    for (int i = original.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

      if (original.equals(reverse))
         System.out.println("The input is a palindrome.");
      else
         System.out.println("The input isn't a palindrome.");
```

The expected result is that the program will recognize that when a sentence is flipped and equals the same thing, then it will print "The input is a palindrome."

Comment: what's your input string?

Comment: The input string is whatever the user enters and the variable for the input is original.

Comment: just post one of your inputs so that we may see why you think that the program does not behave in the way that you expected. otherwise the problem is unclear

Comment: Please enter a sentence: Rise to vote sir
The input that you entered was: rise to vote sir
The input is not a lipogram avoiding the letter E.
The input is not a lipogram avoiding the letter S.
The input isn't a palindrome.

Comment: it is indeed not a palindrome, you are ignoring whitespaces. the reverse is `ris etov ot esir` which is not equal to `rise to vote sir`

Comment: you should remove the spaces first: `original = original.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");`

Comment: `replaceAll("[^a-z]", "")` would be even better, so punctuation doesn't cause problems.

Comment: `replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", "")` if you want to support non-Latin characters, I think